# Entity Framework Validation Errors on Insert with Shadowed Property

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Consider the following scenario:

```
public abstract class Entity
{
    public object Id { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Entity<T> : Entity
{
    public new T Id { get; set; }
}

public class Foo : Entity<Guid>
{
}
```

If I have the following code:

```
var foo = new Foo { Id = Guid.NewGuid() };
db.Foos.Add(foo);
db.SaveChanges();
```

I'm getting a `DbEntityValidation` exception saying that `Id` is not allowed to be null. If I debug, I can see that `Foo.Id` does indeed have a value, but if I go into the base object down to the level of `Entity`, `Id` is null there, and it seems that is what Entity Framework is using to validate against rather than the non-shadowed property. I feel like I'm missing something really basic here; maybe I just haven't had enough coffee yet this morning. Any ideas what might be the problem?

Comment: Could this have anything to do with some sort of lazy loading / eager loading?

Comment: What if you did this `var foo = new Foo(); foo.Id = Guid.NewGuid(); db.Foos.Add(foo); db.SaveChanges();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that

```
public new T Id { get; set; }
```

...in `Entity<T>` hides the Id property in Entity. If you do this:

```
var foo = new Foo { Id = Guid.NewGuid() };
Entity entity = foo as Entity;
Console.WriteLine(entity.Id);
```

...that's not going to return a Guid, it's going to return what's behind Entity.Id which is an object which has not been set.

**Edit:**

Chris came up with this, which should work fine.

```
public abstract class Entity<T> : Entity
{
    public new T Id
    {
        get { return (T)base.Id; }
        set { base.Id = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, your answer, while it technically did not solve my problem, did get me thinking of a possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I missed something simple: Entity Framework is incompetent and doesn't support property shadowing. I thought it did because in the past I've successfully used shadowing to alter property attributes (e.g. make the property only required in a subclass), but I've never gone so far as to actually attempt to change the type.

**UPDATE**

It occurred to me that if I just set the base property with the right value, everything would be fine. So, I changed my `Entity<T>` class to the following:

```
public abstract class Entity<T> : Entity
{
    public new T Id
    {
        get { return (T)base.Id; }
        set { base.Id = value; }
    }
}
```

The exception went away and the object was saved to the database successfully. Are there any unforeseen consequences to doing this that I'm missing?

Comment: I really feel like you were hinting at something like this, but never really came out and said it. It was your answer that jump-started my brain, but I really think this code should be in the accepted answer. If you want to rip it off and update your answer, I'll kill mine and accept yours.

Comment: Cheers :) Leave yours there - makes a more interesting page, showing how the answer was got!